# Powershell array interpreted as single item

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I'm just learning PowerShell, and running into an issue.

I'm trying to use an array to define a collection of folder/file *paths*, and then use that collection in a *foreach* loop. When the loop is executed, it seems to be concatenating the collection into a single path instead of separately processing each item in the array. This results in a path not being found error.

**Code:**

```
        $SourcePathRoot = "C:\Temp\"
        #$SourcePaths = @($SourcePathRoot + "File1.dat", $SourcePathRoot + "File2.txt")
        foreach ($Path in $SourcePaths) {
            Write-Host $Path
            Test-Path $Path }
```

**Output** ($Path and Test-Path $Path):

> C:\Temp\File1.dat C:\Temp\File2.txt
>
> False

I know it's probably something simple - what am I doing wrong?!? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with [*operator precedence*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence) and type-dependent operator behavior in PowerShell.

When evaluating an expression, `,` takes precedence over `+`.

In your example, the `,` operator in the middle of your array expression is therefore evaluated *before* the `+` operators are.

Let's step through:

```bsh
# Okay, this is the raw expression
@($SourcePathRoot + "File1.dat", $SourcePathRoot + "File2.txt")

# , takes precedence and is evaluated first, leaving us with
@("C:\Temp\" + @("File1.data", "C:\Temp\") + "File2.txt")
```

The behavior of `+` depends on the type of the left-hand side operand - which is a string - so PowerShell will attempt string concatenation of the middle array to the first string, resulting in:

```
@("C:\Temp\File1.data C:\Temp\" + "File2.txt")
```

Which is why the result is an array consisting of 1 string with the value `C:\Temp\File1.dat C:\Temp\File2.txt`

---

Solution is simple, just split the array expression into two separate statements:

```bsh
$SourcePaths = @($SourcePathRoot + "File1.dat"; $SourcePathRoot + "File2.txt")
# or 
$SourcePaths = @(
  $SourcePathRoot + "File1.dat"
  $SourcePathRoot + "File2.txt"
)
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias. You're solution worked like a charm!  On a side note, the ISE seems a bit flaky. When I first tried the semis, it didn't seem to work. Likewise, when I split the expression into multiple lines, ISE flagged the ending ")" as missing a starting "(". Once I closed ISE and went back in, there was no issue.